# How to share my localhost on the same network?

Tags: localhost, wildfly-10

I am working on a Java Web project and I am using wildfly 10.1.Final as server. In order test with other computers which are on the same network, I would like to share my localhost. Can anybody help me in this matter? 
Thanks...

Comment: Bind your services to INADDR_ANY (0.0.0.0) rather than 127.0.0.1, and open the relevant inbound ports in your firewall. If that doesn't answer your question, unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Run **wildfly** with command **standalone.bat -b 0.0.0.0** (I suppose, you are using Windows). If linux, then **./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0**

Then disable firewall and your LAN may connect to your IP (port is 8080, not 80)

Actually, you also can share localhost on Linux through ssh tunnel, like

```
ssh -L 127.0.0.1:8080:127.0.0.1:8080 root@server -N
```

but I doubt that you need it.